# Можно ли сделать переключатель с Desktop View на Mobile View?

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap, opencart

Имеется сайт opencart на boostrap с responsive темой, возможно ли сделать переключатель чтоб с desktop версии уходил на mobile и наоборот, можно ли обойтись малой кровью допустим подменять `<meta>` тэг только, или надо лапатить весь boostrap с его viewport @media ? или мудрить js чтоб выкидывал классы типа hidden-xs а на desktop версию наоборот hide(), вообщем хотел бы послушать умных людей :)

Comment: Если не секрет, какую задачу хотите решить с помощью такого переключателя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Бутстрап определяет стили по принципу [«mobile first»](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile). Стили для мобильного — это стили до первого брейкпоинта.

На официальном сайте можно собрать собственный Бутстрап, [увеличив все брейкпоинты в 10 раз](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints). Тогда десктопы попадут в интервал `xs` вместо `lj`.

[image: Customize and download]

Останется вытащить из полученной сборки `bootstrap.css` и по кнопке менять стили с обычных на покорёженные и обратно. На SO есть [варианты переключателей](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846980/). Получится, например, так:

http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/ggdmax

```js
var $style = $('#style');
var $switcher = $('#switcher');
var cssUsual = 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css';
var cssMobile = 'http://glebkema.ru/dist/css/mobile/bootstrap-mobile.css';

$switcher.click(function() {
  if ($switcher.hasClass('btn-primary')) {
    $style.attr('href', cssMobile);
    $switcher.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-warning').text('Переключить на обычный');
  } else {
    $style.attr('href', cssUsual);
    $switcher.removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-primary').text('Переключить на мобильный');
  }
});
```

```css
.row-demo {
  margin-top: 32px;
}
.row-demo > div {
  background: #69c;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.row-demo > div:nth-child(3n+2) { background: #c69; }
.row-demo > div:nth-child(3n+3) { background: #9c6; }
```

```html
<link id="style" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header"><button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button><a href="" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a></div>
    <div id="bs-navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="">Left</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="">Right</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="text-center">
  <button id="switcher" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  <button id="switcher" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Переключить на мобильный</button>
</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-demo">
    <div class="col-sm-2">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">5</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">6</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо! то что нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Вам, возможно, пригодится [вот это](http://mobiledetect.net/)

На странице делаете инклюд - это один файл на php. И условие. Например

```
<?php 
    include 'mobile_detect.php';
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
    if ($detect->isMobile()) {
        //код
    } 
?>
```

Вообще там в примерах всё есть на сайте. Можно детектить удобно и быстро браузеры, типы устройств, ОС и др.

Comment: спасибо, но мне delect ничего не надо, мне надо банально switch, по логике этого switch я могу хоть на desktop иметь мобильный вид, мне не нужно определять устройство.

Comment: так для того, чтобы сделать switch, нужно же знать, когда его делать, нет? Или вы говорите о том, что делать это нужно не автоматически, а только вручную по нажатию на кнопку\ссылку?

Comment: меня код не интересует, switch то я напишу, мне надо логика, как мне отобразить desktop сайт как на мобильнике, допустим для этого надо 1. boostrap.css перепесать все viewport и т.д и т.д, мне нужно просто логика решения)

Comment: Я с boostrap не работал, так что не подскажу конкретно.
Но обычно я бы просто сделал три css. Один обнуляет всё. Второй для десктопа. Третий для мобильного. Ну и крутил бы ими.

Answer (score 0):

В чем проблема то? Проверяешь (если нужно) телефон или десктоп и выводишь соответствующие стили css. Подсказываю if поможет. Ну, а если просто свич, как по задаче - делаешь переключатель и если нажалась кнопка, ну скажем "Перейти на мобильную версию сайта", то по нажатию добавлять куку с именем "mobile" и значением "1" к примеру или для наглядности куку с именем "device_type" и значениями либо  mobile", либо "tablet", либо "pc". Потом делаешь проверку на существование (isset), заполненность (!empty) и в зависимости от типа загружать нужный стиль. Все. Изи же))